# Error: Could not find or load main class: running compiled JAR different errors depending on how I run it

Tags: java, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

PREFACE! I know similar questions have been asked a million times.  I have read MANY hundreds of the previous questions and still cannot find my answer.

I am working on a raspberry pi and trying to run a Java application that is packaged in a Jar file.  It was working fine before I installed the latest Java 1.8_111.  I downgraded and it still didn't work.  I then wiped my pi to defaults and it is still not working.

The current Java version is 1.8.0_65.  I have decided that the java version is irrelevant by installing multiple different versions with the same result.  When I installed a different version no other version was present to cause conflicts.

If I run the jar by simply doing java -jar KitchenScr.jar I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.javafx.main.Main
```

If I run the jar from the supplied shell script(below).  I get the following error.

Script

```
#!/bin/sh

DIRNAME=`dirname $0`
CP=$DIRNAME/KitchenScr.jar

# start uniCenta oPOS
java -cp $CP uk.chromis.kitchenscr.KitchenScr
```

Error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class uk.chromis.kitchenscr.KitchenScr
```

If I left anything out please let me know.

Comment: Does `KitchenScr.jar` actually exist in the given directory? Try printing `$CP` to make sure it's what you think it is. Does the jar file actually contain `uk/chromis/kitchenscr/KitchenScr.class`? --- Also, why are you trying to load `uk.chromis.kitchenscr.KitchenScr` if the jar file wants to load `com.javafx.main.Main`?

Comment: CP = ./KitchenScr.jar 
uk.chromis.kitchenscr.KitchenScr is the main class that I want to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple issue that was staring me in the face.

Error: Could not find or load main class com.javafx.main.Main

Oracle stopped releasing JavaFX for ARM around Update 30 or something.  It worked initially when I first bought my pi, but not after I installed a new OS because a newer version of Java was running.

Downgrade Java or add relevent ARM libraries for JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

mine worked. CP=$DIRNAME/KitchenScr.jar, I changed the capital letters of kitchenscr.jar to CP=$DIRNAME/kitchenscr.jar